# XAML ControlTemplate Trigger Fails for DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'd like to display different combobox images based on IsDropDownOpen. Not sure how to access 'imgArrow' properly.

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox" >
                <Grid Background="{DynamicResource ComboDropdownNormal}" Height="50" Width="326" >
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" >
                        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />

                                    <Image x:Name="imgArrow"
                                           Source="{DynamicResource ComboBoxArrowNormalImage}"
                                           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter>

                    <ToggleButton ClickMode="Press" Focusable="false"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTmp}" />

                    <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" >
                        <ContentControl>
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" 
                                    Background="{DynamicResource ComboDropdownNormal}"
                                    MaxHeight="540" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" >
                            </Border>
                        </ContentControl>
                    </Popup>

                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
<!-- FAILS -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="imgArrow" Property="Image.Source" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxArrowHoverImage}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="imgArrow" Property="Image.Source" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxArrowNormalImage}" />
                    </Trigger>
<!-- FAILS -->
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The bold triggers in the code above fail. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why I can't get bold lines in my code. Both the editor and adding tags doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ControlTemplate` trigger won't be able to find the `Image` element in the `ContentTemplate` of the `ContentPresenter` but you could apply a `Style` to the `Image` element itself directly and remove the `IsDropDownOpen` triggers from the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" >
    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                <Image x:Name="imgArrow" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
                    <Image.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxArrowNormalImage}" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxArrowHoverImage}" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Image.Style>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
</ContentPresenter>
```

Comment: This worked... thanks! I had tried this before, but I think I left out TargetType from the style. The only thing I needed to add to your solution was "Image." in preceding "Source".

Answer (score 0):

In your *scenario*, you should use a `DataTrigger`

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        <Image x:Name="imgArrow"
               Source="{DynamicResource ComboBoxArrowNormalImage}"
               RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" />
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ComboBox}, Path=IsDropDownOpen}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="imgArrow"
                    Property="Source"
                    Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxArrowHoverImage}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

However, I cannot get why you have put the image in a DataTemplate in the ContentPresenter. I'm not sure this is the *right way* of styling.

If you want to change the source of an Image, while `IsDropDownOpen` is `True`, one way is to put everything is a `Grid`:

```
<Grid >
    <ContentPresenter />
    <Image />
    <ToggleButton />
    <Popup/>
</Grid>
```

and set the `BackGround`s and `Trigger`s Propertly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went with the solution from mm8 because it was a bit simpler.